# Modify Publish Metabox location on CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, advanced-custom-fields, publish

I've been struggling with how to do this properly and have yet to find a solution.  I have a CPT with ACF fields.  I can't use a front-end form because I'm synchronizing the CPT across several subsites so need to use the backend form.  I've got it setup and the post form is defaulting to a single column but I cannot move the publish meta box to the bottom of the form... it's positioned below the post title field.  This seems silly.  S

Any help you could provide would be huge!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work so far.

```
    add_filter('screen_layout_columns', 'one_column_on_screen_options');
function one_column_on_screen_options($columns) {
    $columns['post'] = 1;
    return $columns;
}

// Ignore user preferences stored in DB, and serve only one column layout    
add_filter('get_user_option_screen_layout_post', 'one_column_layout');
function one_column_layout($option) {
    return 1;
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_sliding_panel', 'sds_do_meta_boxes', 0, 1 );
function sds_do_meta_boxes( $post )
{
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'sliding_panel', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'sliding_panel', 'normal', 'high', null );
}


function translate_publish( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {
    if( stripos( $untranslated_text, 'Publish' ) !== FALSE ) {
        $translated_text = str_ireplace( 'Publish', 'Save', $untranslated_text ) ;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
if(is_admin()){
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_publish', 99, 3 );
}
```